# Growing up by playing sports

Tags: sports, physique

Someone says that if you play basketball or something like that, your lenght will grow up. Indeed, I don't believe this. By the way, I wanted to take your ideas. What do you think about it?

Regards

Comment: What kind of size are you referring to? Height? Width? ... Length?

Comment: I mean lenght. Got it? So like imagine that a guy with 1.75 lenght, if he does sport, his lenght will grow up.

Comment: What kind of age are we talking about here?

Comment: 13/12 - 18/21 Adolescence. I mean when anabolism > catabolism.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A person's overall height is determined by their genetics. You can stunt a person's growth by malnutrition, but a person can not grow taller than what he or she is destined to be.

The reason people may think sports make people taller is because professional athletes tend to be taller than average. That is because height gives a slight advantage in some sports. It has nothing to do with any kind of extended growth.